# Use an InputBox to enter prices of 4 items

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB. Today I'm working on entering 4 prices for items to purchase using an input box.  I need to create a counter in a loop. The only 2 buttons on the form "Enter Prices" and "Exit". So far this is the code I have (see below). I know something is off. When I run it, I'm allowed to enter 4 numbers. But at the end, when the message box comes up to show my total, it just gives me my last number I entered. I know I've got to change a few things, as I need my numbers to be in currency. Any suggestions as to where I need to go from here to get this up and running?

```
Private Sub btnPrices_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrices.Click

    'Declare a variable as counter and accumulator
    Dim intcount As Integer = 1I
    Dim intAccumulator As Integer = 0I

    'Declare and intialize variable
    Dim strInput As String = ""

    'Number of Items
    Const intNUM_PRICES As Integer = 4

    'Pre-test loop will keep iterating as long as the expression is ture.
    Do While intcount <= intNUM_PRICES
        'Get price of each item purchased
        strInput = InputBox("Enter Price " & intcount, "Price Needed")

        'Add 1 to the counter
        intcount += 1
    Loop

    'Look at the value placed in the
    MessageBox.Show("Your combined Price for all 4 items is: " & strInput)

End Sub
```

Comment: That is still a little confusing to me.  Could you suggest an example?  Don't show me with my code of course.  I just really don't know where to go from this point.  Should I just scratch what I have and start over?

Answer (score 0):

You've only got one variable for the input and each time you call `InputBox` you replace the previous value each time.  If you want a total then you have to add the values, so you need to add the current input to the previous total each time, not replace it.  Make sure that you convert the input to a number and use a numeric variable, because adding strings will actually join them, not add them mathematically.